# Rails 3.1, JQuery UI Datepicker, Simple_Form and Date Format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui, activerecord, simple-form

I'm making a simple scheduling app. I'm trying out simple_form, and I've got a JQuery Datepicker implemented, which returns a date like 04/30/2012.

```
#_form.html.erb
<%= simple_form_for @workout, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :date, :as => :date_picker%>
    <%= f.input :time %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <%= link_to t('.cancel', :default => t("helpers.links.cancel")),
                workouts_path %>
<% end %>

#application.js
$("input.date_picker").datepicker();
```

The problem is that this date is being taken as DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY. I'd like to keep the original format, since that keeps things more natural, but I haven't been able to figure out how to accept the desired date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [formateDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.formatDate) method.

Comment: Not quite, I'm interested in getting rails to accept the default date format, not reformatting the date picker

Comment: I'm trying to make this work, but no matter what I put into formatDate, I get the same xx/xx/xxxx format in the text field.

Comment: Nevermind, I was misunderstanding the options I was giving it!